# How can I get the file size on the Internet knowing only the URL

Tags: python, http, file, download

I want to get the size of an http://.. file before I download it.
I don't know how to use http request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://your-url")
size= f.headers["Content-Length"]
print size
```

Comment: HTTP HEAD is better option. So you don't need download the payload.

Comment: but using `requests` module if I retrieve the file size is different from the one got from urlOpen, see:
`>>> requests.head(url).headers.get('content-length', None)
'8176'
>>> urllib.urlopen(url).info()['content-length']
'38227'
>>> len(requests.get(url).content)
38274`

Answer (score 12):

The [HTTP `HEAD` method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) was invented for scenarios like this (wanting to know data about a response without fetching the response itself). Provided the server returns a [Content-Length header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests) (and supports `HEAD`), then you can find out the size of the file (in octets) by looking at the Content-Length returned.

Answer (score 5):

Here the complete answer:

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen ("http://your-url")
if "Content-Length" in f.headers:
    size = int (f.headers["Content-Length"])
else:
    size = len (f.read ());
print size
```

Comment: Not so hard to write, but that's the neat answer. +1 . Welcome on stackoverflow !

Answer (score 4):

Not all pages have a content-length header. In that case, the only option is to read the whole page:

```
len(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read());
```

Comment: Greate! Most of the commercial website has no content-length header!!